# Imagem ocupando todo monitor

Tags: css

Consegui um código aqui mesmo no `SO` que resolveu em grande parte o problema que tenho, estou tentando deixar a imagem se adequar a várias resoluções de monitoresm o background está correto, a imagem fica no tamanho real, mas fica com bordas nas laterais e não consegui resolver esse detalhe.

O que tenho é isso até o momento:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Café</title>

 <style>


 div{
  width:100%;
  height:1440px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
 }

 .minhaClass{
  background: url('imagens/fundo_cafe.png') no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
 } 


 </style>

</head>

<body>
 <div class="minhaClass"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

E a página pode ser vista nesse link:
[Página modelo](https://www.cafelovat.com.br/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por padrão a tag `body` vem com `margin`.

É bom utilizar o bom e velho:

```
body{
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

Pesquisa por CSS Reset, Normalize. Você vai encontrar bastante conteúdo útil.

Comment: Ajudou muito @Diego Souza, valeu.